# Django: Querying comments based on object field

Tags: django

I've been using the built-in `Django` comments system which has been working great. On a particular page I need to list the latest X comments which I've just been fetching with:

```
latest_comments =   
Comment.objects.filter(is_public=True, is_removed=False)  
.order_by('submit_date').reverse()[:5]
```

However I've now introduced a Boolean field 'published' into the parent object of the comments, and I want to include that in the query above. I've tried using the content_type and object_pk fields but I'm not really getting anywhere. Normally you'd do something like:

```
Comment.objects.filter(blogPost__published=True)
```

But as it is not stored like that I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Which field in the Comment model references the blog post to which the comment is attached?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins its a generic relation.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins It's the comments model defined [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/models/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
posts_ids = BlogPost.objects.filter(is_published=True).values_list('id', flat=True) #return [3,4,5,...]
ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(BlogPost)
latest_comments = Comment.objects.filter(is_public=True, is_removed=False, content_type=ctype, content_object__in=posts_ids).order_by('-submit_date')[:5]
```

Comment: `.values_list('id',)` will return `[(2,), (4,), (5,), ...]`, not ` [3,4,5,...]`

Comment: this will obviously fail once you have few thousands of BlogPosts.

Comment: @Secator, Yes, you're right, I forgot about setting "flat=True"

Comment: @vartec, If we are working with large amounts of data, it is better to use a raw sql queries that would remove unnecessary requests

Answer (score 0):

Comments use [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey) to store the relation to parent object. Because of the way generic relations work related lookups using `__<field>` syntax are not supported.

You can accomplish the desired behaviour using the 'in' lookup, however it'll require lot of comparisons when there'll be a lot of BlogPosts.

```
ids = BlogPost.objects.filter(published=True).values_list('id', flat=True) # Get list of ids, you would probably want to limit number of items returned here
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(BlogPost) # Becasue we filter only comments for BlogPost
latest_comments = Comment.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, object_pk__in=ids,  is_public=True, is_removed=False, ).order_by('submit_date').reverse()[:5]
```

See the [Comment model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/models/) doc for the description of all fields.

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot do that in one query. Comments use [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey). Documentation says:

> Due to the way GenericForeignKey is implemented, you cannot use such
>   fields directly with filters (filter() and exclude(), for example) via
>   the database API.